# How to return a reference to a function (knockout observable) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm hoping I'm asking the right question.

#### Here's the short version of the question - why does `event1` work as I expect but `event2` does not:

```
...
var tobereturned = context.$root.taskId
event1 = {focus: tobereturned}
event2 = {focus: function(tobereturned){return tobereturned;}}
...
```

#### For the complete context - Let me start with this http://jsfiddle.net/4udBL/8/

The goal is to use Knockout's event binding to update my view model when selecting one of several text boxes. That much works in the fiddle above.

I'm using knockout-classbindingprovider to set everything up so there's a good amount of nesting functions within objects within functions etc. At the end of the day I need to provide the "focus" key with a reference to a function I store called `var tobereturned = context.$root.taskId`.

As you can see in the fiddle, with line 52 uncommented `focus: tobereturned`, and line 51 commented `focus: function(tobereturned){return tobereturned;}` this works. Swapping those two lines breaks the databinding.

What fundamental JS concept am I missing that would make this work? Clearly I'm mistaken in thinking those are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you are doing with the `focus` event in `event2`, is putting it as a function whereas it only needs the ref/value of  `context.$root.taskId`.

If you really would like to put that way with a function then you can do the following

```
...
var tobereturned = context.$root.taskId
event1 = {focus: tobereturned}
event2 = {focus: (function(){return tobereturned;})()}
...
```

Comment: that won't work, because you loose the reference to tobereturned.  Try it in the jsfiddle the OP set up.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to bind the function stored in `tobereturned` to an event.  In the first case you pass a reference to that function.  In the second case, you would like to return a reference to the function, but to do so as the result of an immediately called anonymous function.

For this to work, you need to make sure you actually call the anonymous function.  And, in calling it, you need to pass in `tobereturned`.  Just replace your second line with:

```
event2 = {focus: function(tbr){return tbr;}(tobereturned)}}
```

Doing so in your jsfiddle works.